# How to make a SIP support device

Tags: sip

Is it possible to make a SIP support speaker or other devices?
I want to install SIP on my favorite device,How can I install SIP software on it?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your device. Check with your device manual that what is you are allowed to do.

With respect to SIP - If device allows it then yes you can. But just installing SIP stack is not enough. It is beneficial only if you have complete network stack (TCP/IP) in your device. The OS,, which your device is running on, has SIP stack available.

Hope it answers.